# Setting up an SMTP server for VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

We are running VSTS 2015 and I need to set up notifications for pull requests.  When I go into the VSTS online portal and try to set it up, I get this message:

> TF400663: Mail settings are not configured on this server. Please contact your administrator

I am trying to find out how to set up the SMTP server but all of my searches are pointing me to TFSMgmt.exe on the local drive.  I don't have this program.  Do I have to download it, or is there a way to configure the SMTP server through the web portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer no, it can't be done through the web interface and there is not a client to download that will allow the management for TFS, it has to be done on the server (at least for 2015).

So, I had the admin go in and add the SMTP server for me and notifications are now working.